# MSSQL - Insert a row into a table if the row does not already exist in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have this piece of code:

```
insert into table1(column1, column2)
select distinct id, somevalue from table1 where id in (select id from table2)
```

which basically is adding all the id's from table2 to table1 column1, while other columns in table1 share same values for all rows.

Now the problem is that I have to check whether an id from table2 already exists in table1 and only insert if it does not. How can I achieve that?

Comment: As you have written the query `insert into . . .  select id . . . from table1 . . .`, *all* the ids are going to exist in table 1.  Can you edit the question so it makes sense?

Comment: You probably want to use `MERGE`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO table1(column1, column2)
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id, t2.somevalue 
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.id = t1.id
where t1.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
    SELECT distinct id, value 
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ID from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You example insert is a little unclear. It looks like you are inserting the id into Table1.Column1 instead of into Table1.id. However, assuming that the sample is correct. There are a number of ways to do it.

Here's one that is just a little different and possible faster. Faster because of the use of GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT on this sort of simple data and the use of NOT EXISTS instead of a NOT IN or LEFT JOIN.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2)
SELECT id
      ,value
  FROM Table2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Id = Table2.Id) 
 GROUP BY id
         ,value
```